# Clicking on one item changes the background of another item in recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I don't know how to fix it. Below is the video link:
https://www.facebook.com/groups/2297396350278679/permalink/5183111161707169/?app=fbl

Comment: Finally I got solution... . Just using this : final Model model = myModelList.get(position);

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know much about recycleview but i am facing the same problem in the listview,
its happend if you make the background changed for example if(_position==1),
to fix it in simple way dont make the background changed onbind and change it onclick and to change it when the content refreshed you can use .setSelection method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks dear, I tried it, But I am facing the same problem.